# Only zip is getting Attached without HTML Part

Tags: python, shell

While Running the Code, only zip file is getting attached the body is not coming in Mail (HTML FORMAT)
Please let Know if there is any wrong with the code

```
    export to_email_id="abc@example.com"
    export MAILPART=`uuidgen` ## Generates Unique ID
    export MAILPART_BODY=`uuidgen` ## Generates Unique ID
    (
     echo "To: ${to_email_id}"
     echo "Subject: Subject here" ##Subject Here
     echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
     echo "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$MAILPART\""
     echo ""
     echo "--$MAILPART"         
     echo "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$MAILPART_BODY\""
     echo ""
     echo "--$MAILPART_BODY"        
     echo "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1"
     echo "--$MAILPART_BODY"         
     echo "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
     echo "Content-Disposition: inline"
     #filename - it should be attached in body 
     cat $filename          
     echo "--$MAILPART_BODY--"
     echo "--$MAILPART"         
     echo 'Content-Type: application/zip; name="'$(basename abc.zip)'"'
     echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"
     echo 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'$(basename abc.zip)'"'
     echo ""         
     #abc is a zip name
     base64 $ATTACH $(basename abc.zip)
     echo "--$MAILPART--"
    ) | /usr/sbin/sendmail ${to_email_id}
```

Comment: Your question seems to be tagged as a python question, however this appears to be a shell scripting question. Tagging this with shell/posix/bash would help get the right eyes on this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the body part, could you try adding the html tags and relevant message by replacing as desired from below code,

```
echo "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    echo "Content-Disposition: inline"
    echo " <html> " 
    echo " <head> "
    echo " <title> My email </title> "
    echo " </head>"
    echo " <body>"
    echo " <h3>Here we have message-body</h3>"
    echo " </body>"
    echo " </html>"
```

Comment: Could you mark the answer and upvote if it is correct.Also please change the tag from python to shellscripting